# Protractor: How to click on button in modal-dialog (angular element)

Tags: javascript, angular, protractor, modal-dialog

I'm writing automation test for angular application with protractor framework.

**Test scenario:**

1. Click at button: Create PDF Report

   - Modal-dialog window appeared
2. Click at button: Run Report Now within modal-dialog

I have an issue with clicking at button within modal-dialog element.

**I'm getting the following Protracor errors**

1. Failed: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document,
2. Failed: No element found using locator

## Test

```
describe("Managing PDF Project Report", function () {
    it("contain create PDF project for test purpose ", async function () {
        await logIn();
        await element(by.css(".btn-group.pull-right > button ")).click();
        await element(by.css(".dropdown-menu.no-print")).element(by.css("li:nth-child(3) > a")).click();
        await browser.wait(element(by.css(".modal-footer > div > button:nth-child(2)")).click(), 5000);
    });
```

I was also trying to find element by ButtonText, ng-click attribute, but it also did not work.

## HTML

[image]

## Question

I'm a bit confused because this element does not behave like iframe or like browsers pop up's.
Any ideas how can I interact with element inside this modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From which element you are getting those errors? If it's the `Run Report Now` button, you can try with css:

```
element(by.css('[ng-click="createReport()"]');
```

Additionally, I'd suggest adding a couple of explicit waits to make sure Protractor waits properly:

```
const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($$('.modal-dialog .modal-content .modal-footer')), 5000);
await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.css('[ng-click="createReport()"]')), 5000);
await element(by.css('[ng-click="createReport()"]').click();
```

Comment: Yes, its about ```Run Report Now``` button. I used your sugestion without visibilityOf because i have receved ```Wait timed out after``` error. With final code worked perfectly:                                                                                                              ```const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.css('[ng-click="createReport()"]')), 6000));
await element(by.css('[ng-click="createReport()"]')).click();
await browser.sleep(5000);```

Comment: Glad it helped! may I ask why are you using `browser.sleep()` at the end?